# TSQL Conditional Join Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am working on a dynamic query that allows me to define field types in a database table and then pull a list of user defined fields that were selected during the creation of a dashboard along with the values that were chosen for each of the logic operators.

For example, use can choose `field1` which is `employeeID`. They can then provide the ID they want to search by and it will store the `fieldID` and `fieldValue` in a table for when we need to render the data.

Now depending on the field that was chosen, I may need to join up another table to get further information such as the employees name.

While this is simple enough, the tricky part comes into play when having to join the value against multiple possible tables. If I stored an `employeeID`, I would join that field with the employee table. However, if I stored a `storeID`, I would need to join that field with the stores table instead.

Here was my thinking before I got to the end and realized I was stuck. Basically, I was going to say "if this field was a people table `isPeople=1` then join our `employeeTable`.

If this field `isTool=1`, join our tools table.

I essentially have a `fieldType` and a `fieldValue` and based on the type, I need to join a specific table on the value I have stored.

[image]

As I was working through this making it dynamic sql, I realized that I couldn't use the `fl.*` fields to create my `IF` conditions.

ie. `IF (fl.isPeople =1) BEGIN ... JOIN Employee Table ... END`

I thought taking the dynamic approach would have been the only way to do this but now I can't think of a solution to my problem.

**In Conclusion...**

I am trying to join tables and query fields based on a condition. Since I couldn't seem to do that in my normal stored procedure, I tried to do it dynamically and ended up here and this very confusion problem I am trying to explain.

Let me know if I can further clarify.

**Update:**

```
USE [red]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ti2_fetch_dashboard]    Script Date: 9/15/2016 9:55:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Carl
-- Create date: Sept 13, 2016
-- Description: Fetch Single Dashboard for Editing
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ti2_fetch_dashboard_test]
@dashboardID INT, @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Fetch our dashboard
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT d.dashboardID,
           d.dashboardOwner,
           e.PreferredName AS ownerFirst,
           e.LastName AS ownerLast,
           e.NTID AS ownerNTID,
           d.dashboardTitle,
           d.dashboardDescription,
           d.dashboardType,
           d.creator,
           d.timestamp,
           d.lastUpdate,
           d.isDeleted,
           (SELECT sub.QID AS subscriberQID,
                   e.PreferredName AS subscriberFirst,
                   e.LastName AS subscriberLast,
                   e.NTID AS subscriberNTID
            FROM   dbo.ti_dashboard_subscribers AS sub
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   dbo.EmployeeTable AS e
                   ON sub.QID = e.QID
            WHERE  sub.dashboardID = d.dashboardID
            FOR    XML PATH (''options''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT (''subscribers'')),
           (SELECT   f.fid,
                     f.fieldID,
                     f.[order],
                     cfg.primaryAllowed,
                     cfg.secondaryAllowed,
                     cfg.exportAllowed,
                     mf.fieldName,
                     mf.placeholder
            FROM     dbo.ti_dashboards_fields AS f
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboard_field_types AS ft
                     ON f.typeID = ft.fieldTypeID
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboard_master_fields_config AS cfg
                     ON f.fieldID = cfg.fieldID
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboards_master_fields AS mf
                     ON mf.fieldID = f.fieldID
            WHERE    f.dashboardID = d.dashboardID
                     AND ft.fieldTypeName = ''Primary''
            ORDER BY f.[order] ASC
            FOR      XML PATH (''fields''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT (''primaryFields'')),
           (SELECT   f.fid,
                     f.fieldID,
                     f.[order],
                     cfg.primaryAllowed,
                     cfg.secondaryAllowed,
                     cfg.exportAllowed,
                     mf.fieldName,
                     mf.placeholder
            FROM     dbo.ti_dashboards_fields AS f
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboard_field_types AS ft
                     ON f.typeID = ft.fieldTypeID
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboard_master_fields_config AS cfg
                     ON f.fieldID = cfg.fieldID
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboards_master_fields AS mf
                     ON mf.fieldID = f.fieldID
            WHERE    f.dashboardID = d.dashboardID
                     AND ft.fieldTypeName = ''Secondary''
            ORDER BY f.[order] ASC
            FOR      XML PATH (''fields''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT (''secondaryFields'')),
           (SELECT   f.fid,
                     f.fieldID,
                     f.[order],
                     cfg.primaryAllowed,
                     cfg.secondaryAllowed,
                     cfg.exportAllowed,
                     mf.fieldName,
                     mf.placeholder
            FROM     dbo.ti_dashboards_fields AS f
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboard_field_types AS ft
                     ON f.typeID = ft.fieldTypeID
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboard_master_fields_config AS cfg
                     ON f.fieldID = cfg.fieldID
                     INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ti_dashboards_master_fields AS mf
                     ON mf.fieldID = f.fieldID
            WHERE    f.dashboardID = d.dashboardID
                     AND ft.fieldTypeName = ''Export''
            ORDER BY f.[order] ASC
            FOR      XML PATH (''fields''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT (''exportFields'')),
            (SELECT   l.[fieldID],
                    -- Get the details of each of those fields
                     (SELECT fl.queryField,
                             fl.allowMultiple,
                             fl.isPeople,
                             fl.isDate,
                             fl.isSelect,
                             fl.isInput,
                             fl.isTool,
                             fl.selectOptions,
                             -- Get the values associcated with the fields
                             (SELECT dv.value';

                             -- If fl.isPeople = 1
                             SELECT @SQL += ', e.PreferredName AS FirstName, e.LastName, e.NTID, e.QID ';

                             -- If fl.isTool = 1
                             SELECT @SQL += ', t.toolName, t.toolType ';

                             -- Primary Table
                             SELECT @SQL += 'FROM dbo.ti_dashboards_logic AS dv ';

                             -- If fl.isPeople = 1
                             SELECT @SQL += 'LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTable AS e ON dv.value = e.QID ';

                             -- If fl.isTool = 1
                             SELECT @SQL += 'LEFT OUTER JOIN ti_tools AS t ON dv.value = t.tool ';

                             -- Rest of Statement
                             SELECT @SQL += 'WHERE  dv.fieldID = l.fieldID
                                     AND dv.dashboardID = d.dashboardID
                              FOR    XML PATH (''data''), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT (''values''))
                      FROM   dbo.ti_dashboard_master_fields_config AS fl
                      WHERE  fl.fieldID = l.fieldID
                             AND l.dashboardID = d.dashboardID
                      FOR    XML PATH (''fields''), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT (''logicMeta''))
            FROM     [red].[dbo].[ti_dashboards_logic] AS l
            WHERE    l.dashboardID = d.dashboardID
            GROUP BY l.fieldID, l.dashboardID
            FOR      XML PATH (''fields''), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT (''logicFields'')),
            (SELECT sdb.dashboardID ,
                       sdb.fieldID ,
                       sdb.sort ,
                       sdb.[order] ,
                       mf.fieldName
                FROM dbo.ti_dashboards_sorting AS sdb
                JOIN dbo.ti_dashboard_master_fields_config AS sf
                ON sdb.fieldID = sf.fieldID
                JOIN dbo.ti_dashboards_master_fields AS mf
                ON sf.fieldID = mf.fieldID
                WHERE sdb.dashboardID = d.dashboardID
                ORDER BY sdb.[order] ASC
                FOR    XML PATH (''fields''), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT (''sortingFields'')
            )
    FROM   dbo.ti_dashboards AS d
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.EmployeeTable AS e
           ON d.dashboardOwner = e.QID
    WHERE  d.dashboardID = @_dashboardID
           AND d.isDeleted = 0
    FOR    XML PATH (''data''), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT (''root'')';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@_dashboardID INT', @_dashboardID = @dashboardID

END
```

Comment: Post your code (not an image)

Comment: I think you might actually benefit from using a ORM tool so you can make more dynamic queries in your code layer, or you could use multiple queries and extract the data in a few trips to the DB instead of trying to do it all in one go .... I've been down the road you're going and doing dynamically dynamic queries are not a good path. You'll quickly end up with performance issues if your data set is just somewhat large.

Comment: Could you also provide all the fields to the user and leave them blank (`NULL`) and check for that in the join condition? That way you can always join all the tables but only for the parameters that are used.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join tables dynamically, driven by data and different number of columns for each row.

You just need to use UNION to combine the results from multiple SELECT queries. Each SELECT query will have different joins and WHERE statements (isPeople, isTool, etc).

Or you can join all relevant tables and add more conditions in ON statement like below pseudo-code:

```
SELECT e.xxxx, t.yyyy, dv.zzzz, fl.ffff
FROM dbo.ti_dashboards_logic AS dv
   JOIN dbo.ti_dashboard_master_fields_config AS fl ON ....
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTable  AS e ON dv.value = e.QID AND fl.isPeople = 1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ti_tools AS t ON dv.value = t.tool AND fl.isTool = 1
```

So each row has same number of columns, and t.yyyy and e.xxxx will be NULL or not NULL depending on fl.isTool and fl.isPeople values.

Comment: Could you possibly provide some pseudo code for what you are suggesting?

Comment: updated my answer.  The code is really too big and hard to read. You need to split it to multiple parts, using temp tables or table variable.